# How to fix: Trying to capture a data in the options section of chrome extension for local.storage and use elsewhere?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm making a Google Chrome extension that has various parts. It has an iframe, a pop-up and an options page. Currently the iframe and pop-up communicate fine and send the collected data off to a database. However I want to capture some data from the options page (an email address) to be used elsewhere in the app. I planned to do this through capturing the email address and storing it but the code doesn't seem to be working.

I've attached the code I'm trying to use in options.js

```
function save_email(){

var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

chrome.storage.sync.set({
  userEmail: email} );
};


I would hope to see it in local/session storage but nothing is there.
```

Comment: HTML5 `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` is a completely different thing not related to chrome.storage.sync or chrome.storage.local. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and tutorials on using extension storage API.

Comment: that's not my question

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. Your question indicates you're confusing the two different storage APIs. When you use chrome.storage.sync you won't see anything in "local/session storage". You either need to use HTML5 localStorage to store **and** read the value or switch to the extension storage API to both set and get the value as shown in the documentation I've linked.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, is there no way to see if the value has been successfully captured?

Comment: You can open devtools for any extension page/frame and run chrome.storage.sync.get(null, console.log) or use "Storage Area Explorer" extension.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'm trying a different approach now